# only parts of scss showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm working on a project with node.js and webpack.  I'm using scss and almost everything in my style.scss file is showing up correctly except for the content in one box.  Some of the font sizes are showing up correctly but the font is not.  Not all font sizes are correct.  Every other section of the page except for .tripbox is showing up correctly but I have no clue why this one section is giving me problems.  Is it because the text inside the div IDs that I'm trying to style are generated in my updateUI.js and cookies.js files? I've been checking and rechecking my code but I cannot for the life of me spot the error.  Is there something I'm missing?  These are the relevant files:

Also I need the removetrip button to have different width values for the one in the tripbox class and the one in the form class.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.scss">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="banner">
        <header>
                Travel Planner
        </header>
        </div>

        <main>
            <div class="trip">
                <div class="imagebox">

                    <div id="image"></div>

                </div>

                <div class="tripbox">

                        <div id="location"></div>
                        <div id="time"></div>

                    <button id='removeTrip'>Remove Trip </button>

                        <div id="daysUntil"></div>

                        <br>
                        <div class="typical">
                        Typical weather for then is:
                        </div>
                        <div id="high"></div>

                        <div id="forecast"></div>
                        <br><br>




                </div>

            </DIV>
                <center>
                <div class="form">

                    <section>
                    <input id="place" type="text" name="input" value="" placeholder="Enter Location" size="48" required><br>
                    <input id="date" type="text" name="input" value="" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" size="48" required><br>
                    <button id="generate">Submit</button>
                    <button id='removeTrip'>Remove Trip </button>
                    <section>
                </div>
                </center>

        </main>
        <div class="footer">
        <footer>
            <p>Michael Wycklendt      Udacity</p>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.scss

```
$font-stack: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
$tripfont: 'Arvo', serif;


.container{
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-areas: "banner"
                         "trip"
                         "form"
                         "footer";
    .banner{
        grid-area: banner;
        font: 250% $font-stack;
        margin-left: 40px;
    }
    .trip{
        grid-area: trip;
        display: flex;
        height: auto;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 20px;
        background-color: #ffe6dc;
        .imagebox{
            min-width: 300px;
            max-width: 800px;
            padding: 20px;
            img{
                max-width: 100%;
                height: auto;
            }
        }
        .tripbox{
            padding: 20px;
            #location{
                font: $tripfont;
                font-size: 120%;
            }
            #timw{
                font: $tripfont;
                font-size: 120%;
            }
            #daysUntil{
                font: $font-stack;
                font-size: 110%;
            }
            #typical{
                font: $font-stack;
                font-size: 110%;
            }
            #high{
                font: $font-stack;
            }
            #forecast{
                font: $font-stack;
            }
            #removeTrip{
                padding: 15px;
                font: $font-stack;
                font-size: 14px;
                background-color: white;
                border-color: black;
                border: 2px solid black;
                width: 35%;
                &:hover{
                    background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
                }
            };
        }

    }
    .form{
        grid-area: form;
        font: $font-stack;
        input[type=text]{
            width: 35%;
            padding: 20px 25px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font: $font-stack;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
    }
    .footer{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}

#generate{
    padding: 15px;
    font: $font-stack;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 18%;
    &:hover{
        background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    }
};

#removeTrip{
    padding: 15px;
    font: $font-stack;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 18%;
    &:hover{
        background-color: rgb(211, 211, 211);
    }
};
```

updateUI:

```
const Cookies = require('js-cookie');

let datediff = function (first, second){
    return Math.round((second - first)/(1000*60*60*24))
}
const updateUI = async () =>{
    const res = await fetch('/results');
    console.log(res);
    try {
        console.log(res.data)
        const allData = await res.json();
        console.log(allData)
        console.log(allData)

        let month = allData.two.month
        let day = allData.two.day
        let year = allData.two.year

        let date = new Date(year, month - 1, day )

        var today = new Date()

        let daysUntil = datediff(today, date)

        console.log(daysUntil)

        console.log(today)
        Cookies.set('save', 'saved', {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('date', allData.zero.date, {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('place', allData.zero.place, {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('high', allData.three.high, {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('low', allData.three.low, {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('forecast', allData.three.forecast, {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('image', allData.four.image, {expires: 365});
        Cookies.set('daysUntil', daysUntil)
        let save = Cookies.get('save');
        console.log(save)
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = 'My trip to: ' + allData.zero.place;
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = 'Departing: ' + allData.zero.date;
        document.getElementById("daysUntil").innerHTML = allData.zero.place + ' is ' + daysUntil + ' days away.'
        document.getElementById("high").innerHTML = 'High - ' + allData.three.high + ', Low - ' + allData.three.low ;
        document.getElementById("forecast").innerHTML = allData.three.forecast;
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + allData.four.image + '">';
        return allData;
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
};

export { updateUI }
```

cookies.js:

```
const Cookies = require('js-cookie');

document.getElementById('removeTrip').addEventListener('click', removeTrip);

const resultsCheck = function() {
    if (Cookies.get('save')){
        let place = Cookies.get('place');
        let date = Cookies.get('date');
        let high = Cookies.get('high');
        let low = Cookies.get('low');
        let daysUntil = Cookies.get('daysUntil')
        let forecast = Cookies.get('forecast');
        let image = Cookies.get('image')
        document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = 'My trip to: ' + place;
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = 'Departing: ' + date;
        document.getElementById("daysUntil").innerHTML = place + ' is ' + daysUntil + ' days away.'
        document.getElementById("high").innerHTML = 'High - ' + high + ', Low - ' + low ;
        document.getElementById("forecast").innerHTML = forecast;
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + image + '">';
    }
}

resultsCheck();


function removeTrip(event) {
    if(Cookies.get('save')){
        Cookies.remove('save');
        Cookies.remove('place');
        Cookies.remove('date');
        Cookies.remove('high');
        Cookies.remove('low');
        Cookies.remove('forecast');
        Cookies.remove('image');
        alert('Trip Removed')
    }
}


export { removeTrip }
export { resultsCheck }
```